# Dealing with censored dates as regressors

Tags: regression, time-series, censoring

I'm estimating a linear model, with one of the independent variables being a date of appearance. I consider the date to be a minimum date of appearance, not an obeserved one. Thus it is censored. What would be the proper estimation to approach this?